# Pandas conditional mean of column where values greater than or less than zero

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the conditional mean of a column:
If the values of the row elements are >0 then calculate mean of all such elements and if <0 then calculate the mean of these and store in avgGain and avgLoss.

Input:

```
ProfitLoss
    -8.000
    14.400
    13.150
     3.050
    -8.000
    -8.000
     3.425
     7.350
    -8.000
    -8.000
     0.000
```

Output:

```
avgGain     avgLoss
 8.275      -8.000
```

All these calculations should happen using either pandas apply or aggregate functions in a single statement.

Thanks

Comment: Did you even try anything before asking people to write code for you?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I did try the approaches by more than 2 passes. one  creating arrays of >0 vals and <0 and running mean on the same. I wanted pandas function to be able to do this in single pass. That is the reason it was specified that i want it using pandas apply agg.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, could do:

```
# Setup (for reproducibility)
import pandas as pd

data = [-8.000,
    14.400,
    13.150,
     3.050,
    -8.000,
    -8.000,
     3.425,
     7.350,
    -8.000,
    -8.000,
     0.000]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["ProfitLoss"])

# Calculate the respective means (vectorized)
avgGain = df[df['ProfitLoss'] > 0].mean().values[0]
avgLoss = df[df['ProfitLoss'] < 0].mean().values[0]

# Print outputs to console
print("avgGain:", avgGain)
print("avgLoss:", avgLoss)
```

outputs:

```
Matthews-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow matt$ python test.py
avgGain: 8.275
avgLoss: -8.0
```

as desired

Comment: I know reputation is cool but writing code for someone who doesn't even care to put any effort into asking for it is just **bad**.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli There is clear effort here. OP has strung together input/output, and has asked a clear question. There is no code, but there is indeed significant effort.

Comment: Please tell me you're joking for god's sake.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I thought of not adding my code coz it would work but won't be efficient and might distract. I wanted an efficient way of achieving this. Not sure why you got offended. There were existing questions of conditional mean but those were w.r.t to conditions in other columns.

Comment: Whatever dude nevermind, mine is just a lost cause, have fun with your statistics.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli No, it's not a joke. Have you read the new terms of service here on stackoverflow? This site is extremely harsh to new users: it doesn't have to be that way. Not everyone here is a professional programmer or software engineer: and that's okay. Calm down my friend

Comment: @MattMessersmith That's right, but if you actually read the guidelines you'll discover that questions like this one that are just "I have X and want Y write me the code" without adding at least a reason or what has been tried to solve the problem so far are clearly off-topic. Being more welcoming doesn't mean enforcing this kind of behavior which is just bad.

Comment: I agree with @MattMessersmith. And not everyone can be an expert in every language or library in the world. Programmers come here to learn. Every tool has a learning curve. A one liner code snippet written using a tool designed for it can immensely impact the time to market of the code. I wouldn't try and screw reputation scores of people just because i think a certain way. I'm sure adding code that uses numpy array or for loop wouldn't have helped calm you down :-)